# detecting numerous colored circles in an image using opencv

Tags: opencv, colors, geometry, object-detection

So im trying to detect all the balls like in the image but as you can see not all are being detected. ive been playing around with the parameters for last 2 hours and cant get any more balls detected. my detection code is below. please help. my head is fried.[image]

```
    IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    //covert to grayscale
    cvCvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // This is done so as to prevent a lot of false circles from being detected
    cvSmooth(gray, gray, CV_GAUSSIAN, 5, 5);

    IplImage* canny = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);


    //detect circles
    CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles(canny, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 27.0, 80, 64,0,0);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717010/not-detecting-multiple-circles-in-image

Comment: And another one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734377/cv-hough-circle-parameters-to-detect-circles

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to try SIFT algorithm using a ball as a template to extgract SIFT descriptors. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/find-object/) is an example of how to do object detection with this kind of descriptors.

If you want to stick to your canny aproach, then play with the ball size limit.

Good luck.